# Remove all other properties from object leave only selected

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to remove all array members that are not based on property given, here is example I have something like this

```
    const idToStay = 1;

    const objList = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'aaa',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'bbb',
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        name: 'ccc',
      },
    ];
```

I need to remove all others objects that does not have id with number 1, I know how to remove but how to stay and remove all others

Here I can remove like this

```
const filteredObjList = objList.filter(x => !idsToRemove.includes(x.id));

console.log(filteredObjList);
```

Comment: `but how to stay and remove all others` invert the filter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 2):

It's the same thing, just without the exclamation mark

```js
const idToStay = 1;

const objList = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'aaa',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'bbb',
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        name: 'ccc',
      },
    ];
    
    
const filteredObjList = objList.filter(x => idToStay === x.id);

console.log(filteredObjList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you.

```
    var filtered = objList.filter(function(el) { return el.id === 1; });
    console.log(filtered);
```

Thanks, Mark it as answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const objList = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'aaa',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bbb',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'ccc',
      },
    ];
    
var filtered = objList.filter((el) => el.id === 3 );
console.log(filtered);
```